# Can large positions make the market move because of it on a short term?

Tags: stocks, trading-volume, nasdaq

The NASDAQ shows a Tick Volume of aprox 400 in a 1 minute time period, which I asume means 400 positions placed in one minute?

What happens in the short term if someone decides to buy say 10,000 shares of NASDAQ? Will it cause the market to go up immediately? Will it go down?

Comment: Any time there’s a sudden high demand, higher than regular volume, the price is pushed up a bit. How much depends on the actual volumes.

Answer (score 1):

It is called market impact, and institutions have all sorts of tools to estimate it.

Nowadays, with algorithmic trading, an order to buy or sell 100,000 shares gets turned into a computer-generated set of 1,000 orders of 100 shares to try to hide it.

Market makers sort of first adjust prices to reflect overall market sentiment, then second to adjust to supply-demand imbalance.